# Codeception: only show comment message

Tags: php, codeception

After run test project by this command    `php codecept.phar run api  LoginCest.php --steps` I get the following output:

```
* am trying  to login.........
* I have http header "Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
* I send post "?",{"operation":"login","username":"xyz@abc.com","accessKey":"xyz"}
* I grab data from json response 
* see test status:Passed.
```

But I get only this output:

```
 * am trying  to login.........
 * see test status:Passed.
```

Here is my code:

```
    $I->comment(" am trying  to login.........");
    $postData = array(
        'operation' => 'login',
        'username' => $username,
        'accessKey' => $password
    );
    $url = "?";
    $I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    $I->sendPOST($url, $postData);
    $outputData = $I->grabDataFromJsonResponse();

    if ($outputData['success'] == true) {
        $I->comment("see test status:Passed.");
    } else {
        $I->comment("see test status:Failed.");
    }
```

get only this method output:

```
 $I->comment();
```

Answer (score 0):

Run codeception in debug mode with the option -d

```
php codecept.phar run -d
```

Comment: Thanks. but it not work.It shown all message but I get only $I->comment(); message.